# JSZip load multiple files with Promise.all in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, internet-explorer-11, jszip

We are developing a tool for users to upload zip packages to an intranet site at our company. We are using [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to check inside the zip files and be sure the meet with certain policy and format guidelines.

We look for certain files inside the zip and there may be 0 to 3 xml files we are specifically interested in. We then want to expand those files and check some of their contents once they are all loaded.

I followed [this suggestion](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/375) for how to do that:

```
var zip = JSZipObject...

var promises = [];
var fileList = [file0,file1...fileX];

fileList.forEach(function(file){
    promises.push(zip.file(file.name).async('string'));
});

return Promise.all(promises);
```

And this works great in Chrome, but in [IE there is no native Promise support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility).

Unfortunately most of our company is still using IE11, so I need to come up with a solution that will work in both Chrome and IE11.

I am familiar with the jQuery versions of promises and have used a similar trick with them to wait until all have been resolved.

```
return $.when.apply(null,[promises]);
```

But that doesn't seem to work because the promises returned by `zip.file().async()` aren't jQuery promises.

Is there a way that I can wrap the JSZip promises in jQuery or some other way that I can deal with this?

Comment: Why not use a proper Promise polyfill instead of jQuery?

Comment: Because we've been in IE11 (and earlier) land for so long, most of our pages already have jQuery on them -- so it is easy and already there. But if you have a small one that you can recommend let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the jszip promises to jQuery promises using something like this (I haven't tested it, but you get the idea):

```
function promiseToDeferred(p) {
  var dfd = jQuery.Deferred()

  p
    .then(function(x) { dfd.resolve(x) })
    .catch(function(err) { dfd.reject(err) })

  return dfd.promise()
}
```

So your bit of code would look something like:

```
var fileList = [file0,file1...fileX]

var promises = fileList
  .map(function(file) { return zip.file(file.name).async('string') })
  .map(promiseToDeferred)

return jQuery.when.apply(null,[promises])
```

Comment: This did it. Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ufqetb1g/. Although in the end I did find a polyfill https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill